# Is it possible to create a dynamic unit test?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, dynamic, reflection

I currently have some tests running, which ensure, that for every class implementing a specific interface, I got some things respected.

This is currently running in a winform application, which allow me to give a result for every class, if they are ok or if something is wrong.

I would like to transform this into a TestClass/TestMethod, but I currently don't see how.

The issue is that I need to get a results for every class(or at least have an error for each individual class which is not working.

Currently I've this piece of code:

```
foreach (Type type in GetTypesToCheck())
{
    m_logger.Debug("Checking type " + type.FullName);
    FieldInfo staticField;
    dynamic definition;
    if (CheckStaticField(type, out staticField) && CheckDefinitionPresent(type) && CheckParentDefinition(type, staticField, out definition) && CheckRegistration(type, definition) &&
        CheckSubTypes(type, definition))
    {
        m_logger.Information(type.FullName + ": OK");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make this kind of check with UnitTests and having one result per class(or multiple results for every class)?

Comment: I assume you are using MSTest as a testing framework?

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't think to mention this

Comment: So you basically want to condense multiple test cases into a single test case? A test can either be success or failure in MSTest, so if you had even one failure then everything would fail. This seems counterproductive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store failed types in a temporary collection and then perform required assertion(s) on that collection.

Below is an example:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var failedTypes = new List<Type>(); //to keep failed types

        foreach (Type type in GetTypesToCheck())
        {
            FieldInfo staticField;
            dynamic definition;
            if (!CheckStaticField(type, out staticField) 
                    || !CheckDefinitionPresent(type) 
                    || !CheckParentDefinition(type, staticField, out definition)
                    || !CheckRegistration(type, definition) 
                    || !CheckSubTypes(type, definition))
                failedTypes.Add(type);
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(
            failedTypes.Count == 0, 
            "Failed types: " + string.Join(", ", failedTypes)
            );
    }
}
```